# SQL Server how to seperate date range to date from and date to

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table that is in a format( MM-DD-YYYY to mm-dd-yyyy) now I need to separate the column into 2 columns , one that has MM-DD-YYYY and one that has mm-dd-yyyy! IS there a query to do it!??

edit: sorry if i have comfused you all! My qn is i have a column date containing the following value 12-08-2014 to 12-15-2014, now i need 12-08-2014 in a 'from' column and 12-15-2014 in 'to' column.

Comment: And what is the difference between those formats?  12-03-2015 is MM-DD-YYYY or mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: There is a query but you have to write it.   Google PATINDEX and SUBSTRING and you will have the tools to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`'MM-DD-YYYY'` is [format style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) 110 (US)

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(date,LEFT(MyColumn,10) ,110)
 ,CONVERT(date,RIGHT(MyColumn,10),110)
FROM MyTable
```